# Read an array of values from XML with Boost.PropertyTree

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I have this example XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Root>
  <ChildArray>
    1.0  0.0 -1.0
  </ChildArray>
</Root>
```

I am trying to read it using Boost.PropertyTree, trying the following:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

struct VectorXML
{
    std::array<float, 3> _data;
    void load(const std::string &filename);
};

void VectorXML::load(const std::string &filename)
{
    // Create empty property tree object
    pt::ptree tree;

    // Parse the XML into the property tree.
    pt::read_xml(filename, tree);

    _data=
        tree.get<std::array<float, 3>>("Root.ChildArray");
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        VectorXML v;
        v.load("data.xml");
        std::cout << "Success\n";
        std::cout
            << "X: " << v._data[0] << " "
            << "Y: " << v._data[1] << " "
            << "Z: " << v._data[2] << "\n";
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't compile (`>>` overload in `stream_translator.hpp` doesn't accept `std::array`s).

I guess I will have to iterate through the data manually but I can't come up with the way to retrieve data from this node, documentation isn't clear on how to access data in nodes with more than 1 value...

Something like

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    _data[i] = tree.get<float>("Root.ChildMatrix.???");
```

But it doesn't work (node has 3 floats and boost fails to convert to "float").

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was easy and I am an idiot for not trying a bit more. I won't mark this as
the answer in case someone posts a better one.

I have expanded the answer to accomodate matrices of any dimension (assuming you
add attribute `Size="M N"` to the node).

#### Answer to the original question

```cpp
std::stringstream iss(
    tree.get_child("Root.ChildArray")
        .data() // string
);
float number = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    if (iss >> number)
        _data[i] = number;
```

#### Extended answer

Here I add an attribute check to read the dimensions (note that this can be
improved, especially for more dimensions, and this one still uses the
`array<float,3>` instead of a fully dynamic container).

```cpp
// probably can be done in a more elegant way
std::stringstream iss(
    tree.get<std::string>("Root.ChildArray.<xmlattr>.Dimensions")
);
size_t M = 0;
iss >> M;
// *********
iss.str(
    tree.get_child("Root.ChildArray")
        .data()
);
_data.resize(M);
float number = 0;
for (size_t row = 0; row < M; row++)
{
    for (size_t col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    {
        if (iss >> number)
        {
            _data[row][col] = number;
        }
    }
}
```

Try it with following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Root>
  <ChildArray Dimensions="2 3">
    1.0  0.0 -1.0
    0.0  0.4  1.0
  </ChildArray>
</Root>
```